# Integrando Leitor Código de Barras no Android

Tags: android

Estou tentando adicionar a funcionalidade de ler código de barras ao meu aplicativo através do com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.

Adicionei as chamadas ao aplicativo via Intent de acordo com o código abaixo:

```
static final String ACTION_SCAN = "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.codigodebarras, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        String aux;
        super.onStart();

        UpdateView();

    }

    private void UpdateView() {

        scanQR = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scanQR);
        scanQR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
                    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    CustomDialogSimNao cdsn = new CustomDialogSimNao(getActivity(), "Nenhum scanner foi encontrado. Deseja fazer o download?");
                    cdsn.show();
                }
            }
        });

        scanCode = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.scanCodBar);
        scanCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_SCAN);
                    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    CustomDialogSimNao cdsn = new CustomDialogSimNao(getActivity(), "Nenhum scanner foi encontrado. Deseja fazer o download?");
                    cdsn.show();
                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
                String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
                String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Content:" + contents + " Format:" + format, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }
```

A aplicação é chamada normalmente e o resultado volta ao meu aplicativo como deveria ser, porém ocorre dois problemas e gostaria que se possível me ajudassem nessas questões.

1. Quando executo o aplicativo normalmente ele reconhece os códigos de barras muito rapidamente, mas quando é chamada via Intent pelo meu aplicativo ele tem muito dificuldade para ler os mesmo códigos de barras.
2. Não consigo localizar o numero nos resultados retornados para a minha aplicação.

Como fazer a chamada corretamente para que ele possa reconhecer os códigos rapidamente? Onde localizo o código do código de barras nas informações devolvidas?

Grato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi as questões. Retirei as linhas:

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
```

e

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
```

A adição dessas linhas restringem o tipo de código que o leitor poderá ler e causa a demora além de confundi-lo, pois devolve um código errado quando a leitura é executada.

Sem as linhas acima funciona correta e rapidamente. E descobri que podemos adicionar a seguinte linha:

```
intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "SCAN_MODE");
```

Adicionei e funciona também corretamente.